# 18th core on my 13900k is experiencing constant 43% load, how to find the root cause of this behaviour

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, cpu, troubleshooting

I am very confused by the load on my i9-13900k. It's always the same 18th core and only that one specific core.

I tried to kill every process running on that said core but the load still persists. Can this be just a bug (an extremely wild guess) with how the load is calculated?

I'm running kernel 6.1.9 with a up to date manjaro installation and with default intel integrated graphics

also here is the output from `ps -elyww --sort=time` https://pastebin.mozilla.org/Uj53X3H0

[image: screenshot from htop showing the load]

Answer (score 0):

Here's the deal.

> a bug with how the load is calculated

That's 99.99% unlikely.

I presume the 18th core is one of E-cores which are modest in terms of performance.

The issue here is that you have the CPU frequency feature at work. When your system is not loaded CPU cores are either parked completely or idling at the lowest possible frequency which is AFAIK around 800MHz for your E-cores.

That 43% load could be e.g. audio playing, pipewire daemon or a background service such as irqbalance.

Anyways, if you want to get more info, show the entire htop/top output **as text** sorted by CPU time.

Comment: The load is constant since the first second i installed manjaro (before installing anything else)
The thing about the bug is just a wild guess (i'll put that in my question), also add output from ps